# Exception in plugin Android Support: SAXParseException; Premature end of file

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

After temporarily working on my project on a Mac, I updated my SVN again with the newly committed files on Windows.

When I click **Run**, it says *"Initializing ADB..."*, it does not find my connected Android phone anymore, and it shows Internal IDE error in the top right corner of the screen. When I click on it, it shows the following error:

```
Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parseImpl(DeviceParser.java:483)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parse(DeviceParser.java:455)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.loadDevices(DeviceManager.java:649)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initSysImgDevices(DeviceManager.java:385)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initDevicesLists(DeviceManager.java:253)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDevice(DeviceManager.java:184)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1579)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1479)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:373)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:411)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.initIfNecessary(AvdManagerConnection.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.getAvds(AvdManagerConnection.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker$3.run(DevicePicker.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)



org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parseImpl(DeviceParser.java:483)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parse(DeviceParser.java:455)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.loadDevices(DeviceManager.java:649)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initSysImgDevices(DeviceManager.java:385)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initDevicesLists(DeviceManager.java:253)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDevice(DeviceManager.java:184)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1579)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1479)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:373)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:411)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.initIfNecessary(AvdManagerConnection.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.getAvds(AvdManagerConnection.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker$3.run(DevicePicker.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)



org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parseImpl(DeviceParser.java:483)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parse(DeviceParser.java:455)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.loadDevices(DeviceManager.java:649)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initSysImgDevices(DeviceManager.java:385)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initDevicesLists(DeviceManager.java:253)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDevice(DeviceManager.java:184)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1579)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1479)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.reloadAvds(AvdManager.java:725)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection.getAvds(AvdManagerConnection.java:260)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker$3.run(DevicePicker.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

I tried to delete the .idea folder, clear the cache, clean the project and restarted, but nothing seemed to work.

Any ideas?